# Pass-through query with user input as filter criteria - MS Access

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ms-access, vba, pass-through

I am currently have an USER INTERFACE (a Form) in Access which has two combo boxes referring to a specific date of a quarter. The form values are queried in from a pass through query from SQL SERVER 2008.

Is there any way in which I can write a pass through query which will use the form values in where condition.

For eg : 
INSERT INTO TBL.ABC
SELECT * FROM TBL.DEF where [Date]=Formvalue

After all of the research and I even have gone through couple of questions posted in Stackoverflow, but couldnt find the answer. Is this even possible ??

The main motive behind doing this is to segregate the data into two different tables based on the input as a form of "FormValue" and then perform different operations based on the dates.

Please do let me kno if you need further information. Any help is much appreciated!!

```
Private Sub Command13_Click()
Dim St001, St002 As String
Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
Dim strPath As String
Dim strDate As String
Set conn = CurrentProject.Connection

strPath = "ServerName"
'conn.Open = "ODBC;DRIVER=SQL Server;SERVER=" & strpath & ";
'             DATABASE=DB;UID=ABC;PWD=DEF;Trusted_Connection=No;"

'DoCmd.OpenQuery "003a Drop Curr_Qtr"
strDate = curQtr & ""
StrDate2 = prevQtr & ""

       ' If combo box is empty?
If strDate = "" Then
        MsgBox "The Curr Qtr Date value is Empty, Please select the date"
ElseIf StrDate2 = "" Then
        MsgBox "The Date Prev Qtr Date value is Empty, Please select the date"
Else
    ' Append values

DoCmd.OpenQuery "003a Drop Curr_Qtr"

'On Error Resume Next
St002 = "SELECT COLUMNS into TblB from TblA where ColA='" & strDate & "'
DoCmd.RunSQL St002
```

As scuh, all the tables that I am reffering to in the code are linked tables. I tried using the below format of the code as suggested in one of the form, but it is the same error that pops up all the time :

```
    Dim St001, St002 As String
    Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim strPath As String
    Dim strDate As String
    Set conn = CurrentProject.Connection

    strPath = "ServerName"
    'conn.Open = "ODBC;DRIVER=SQL Server;SERVER=" & strpath & ";DATABASE=DBName;
    '       UID=Username;PWD=password;Trusted_Connection=No;"

    'DoCmd.OpenQuery "003a Drop table"
    strDate = curQtr & ""
    StrDate2 = prevQtr & ""


       ' If combo box is empty?
    If strDate = "" Then
            MsgBox "The Curr Date value is Empty, Please select the date"
    ElseIf StrDate2 = "" Then
            MsgBox "The Prev  Date value is Empty, Please select the date"
    Else
        ' Append values

    DoCmd.OpenQuery "003a truncate table"

    'conn.Open = "ODBC;DRIVER=SQL Server;SERVER=" & strPath & ";DATABASE=009;
    '       UID=GM_SA;PWD=gmsa;Trusted_Connection=No;"

    'On Error Resume Next

 St002 = "Insert Into [Tabl B] ([Tabl B].[ColA]" & _
 "Select [Tabl A].[Col A] from [tabl A].[Col A] where [Tabl A].[Col z]='" & strDate & "'"

 strCon = "ODBC;DRIVER=SQL Server;SERVER=" & strPath & ";DATABASE=DBName;UID=UserName;" _
    & "PWD=Password;Trusted_Connection=No"
    Set wksp = DBEngine(0)
    Set dabs = wksp.opendatabase("", False, False, strCon)
    dabs.Execute St002, dbSQLpassThrough

    End If
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following, after making sure you have a reference to `Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.8 Library`

```
Dim adoConn As ADODB.Connection
...
St002 = "Insert Into [Tabl B] ([ColA]) Select [Tabl A].[Col A] from [tabl A].[Col A] where [Tabl A].[Col z]='" & FORMAT(strDate,"yyyy-mm-dd") & "'"
strCon = "ODBC;DRIVER=SQL Server;SERVER=" & strPath  & ";DATABASE=DBName;UID=UserName;PWD=Password;Trusted_Connection=No"
adoConn.Open(strCon)
adoConn.Execute St002
```

Using ADO instead of DAO is often a better option when passing queries directly to servers, it should completely bypass any possibility of errors similar to "RUNTIME ERROR 3024 - Could not find file 'H:\TableName.Mdb"

Also, if you need a value from a combo column other than the bound column, use `Me.DateCombo.Column(1)` or similar.  Access uses 0-based indexes, so `Me.DateCombo.Column(1)` refers to the second column.

Comment: Is this applicable to Pass Through Queries even?? when i tried to use the suggested query, the vba couldnt identify the datbase (my assumption) as returns an error "RUNTIME ERROR 3024 - Couldnot find file 'H:\TableName.Mdb". I am not sure of the reason

Comment: Please post the code you're using. It seems as if you are *intending* to use a pass-through query, but that Access thinks you are trying to query *it*, not SQL Server.

Comment: yes, agree with Monty Wild that more info is needed.  Suggest you edit your post above to include a version of the query that works.  Then we can suggest ways to generate that based on user input.

Comment: please find the code attached as suggested! I have been trying various ways of fixing this, but nothing seems to be working

Comment: I have also uploaded the chaged code, that I came across in one of the forum, but it did not seem to work either..                                  @MontyWild : My aplogies for the delay in uploadin the code

Comment: Thank you @MontyWild.. I realised the part where the Access was unable to recognize the table names. I was using the table names in the format of [Database].[Schema].[TableName] where as in my access database, it read it as [Database_Schema_TableName].. This finally worked.. :D